# .htaccess redirect pagination

Tags: .htaccess, pagination

At present my url structure of page is like this

Mysite.com/page-2
mysite.com/categoryname/page-2

I want to change it to

mysite.com/page/2/
mysite.com/category/categoryname/page/2/

Note that, I have multiple page, i.e. let's say a category have 100 page so I need to redirect all the earlier page number to the new url structure. Writing code of every url will be too tedious. I am not sure but using $ in the code can help.

Please let me know how can it be done via .htacess.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL structure is already with the desired one you have as I can see.

/category/telecom-news/page/2